# How to make 3 dimensions instead of 4 for training a model?

Tags: python, keras

How to solve that problem?

```
train_images = train_images / 255.0

model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(48, 48)),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(26, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=10)
```

Stacktrace:

```
line 75, in <module>
    model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=10)
  File "C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\sit
e-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1154, in fit
    batch_size=batch_size)
  File "C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\sit
e-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 579, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='input')
  File "C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\sit
e-packages\keras\engine\training_utils.py", line 135, in standardize_input_data
    'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected flatten_1_input to have 3 dimens
ions, but got array with shape (20000, 48, 48, 3)
```

Comment: Please put the full stacktrace of the error, _as text_, into your post. Not as an image.

Comment: I suggest you improve your question, add some examples, some code and make it more clear and add your source code, Have a look here => [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are providing your model a three dimensional input. You are probably using colored images of 48x48 pixels. The last 3 in your input shape is the channel (48, 48, 3). You may want to either use Conv2D layers or simply flatten your entire input across channels.

Comment: Where can I read about resizing images? As I understand it's better make them at least 10x10?  And how "flatten your entire input across channels" you mean I should make it colorless?

Comment: No there are many approaches to the problem. You do not have to make it colorless. You do not have to make them at least 10x10. You have 3 channels Red Green Blue, each one has 48 x 48 = 2304 numbers so flatenning across channels will return a vector with 2304 * 3 = 6912 numbers. Your network is ready to accept only 2304 numbers because of the way you defined your input so change it to input_shape = (48, 48, 3)

Comment: thanks, it works fine. But is there some kind of optimization? My cmd says it will take 42 HOURS to train one epoch. My PK isn't so new. Any advises?

Comment: Well you have many images and they are of large size. Idk just add  batch_size=n_batch inside your model fit. Set n_batch to a number like 32.